# Working with Python, files

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, conda, netcdf

I have some data files which I need to read. I know I should use Dataset, but is there a way how to download these files without downloading them manually but by its URL? How would it look like in my case. I am working with conda-python and netCDF4. Whatever I do I cannot read these files. Sorry for my English. The source is http://meop40.troja.mff.cuni.cz:11180/gw.projekt/data.stratopauza/netcdf.profily/

My first try:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np

my_example_nc_file = '/Users/Leif/Downloads/my_example_nc_data.nc'
fh = Dataset(my_example_nc_file, mode='r')
```

Another Try:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap, shiftgrid, cm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from netCDF4 import Dataset

url = 'http://meop40.troja.mff.cuni.cz:11180/gw.projekt/data.stratopauza/netcdf.profily/atmPrf_C001.2010.227.00.03.G04_2013.3520_nc '
etopodata = Dataset(url) **Error**
```

Comment: Why can't you use urllib.urlopen to read the files.

Comment: Please provide code on what you have done so far.

Comment: I tried, it didn't work, I must have written something wrong. I will write that code down.

Comment: Fot one file it worked (I was trying various examples), but not for those I have listed here unfortunately no.

Comment: what do you mean by "but is there a way how to download these files without downloading them manually but by its URL?"

Comment: Like I don't want to use /Users/Leif/etc.nc but I want to download it directly from the web.

Comment: In the [netcdf4 Documentation](http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/#section1) it says that you need to install `netcdf4` with `openDAP` support (`--enable-dap`) in order to use urls directly. Otherwise you will have to download the file (at least temporarily) to your disk.

Comment: NetCDF4.Dataset() can only use remote files served by a service supporting the OPeNDAP protocol, e..g [THREDDS](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/thredds/current/tds/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe save the contents to a temporary file?

```
import urllib.request

response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

with open("./tempfile", "w") as f:
    f.write(response.read())
```

Now the file `./tempfile` can be used normally

Comment: Can you explain it more broadly, unfortunately I am not a programmer. I don't understand what I am going to use next.

Comment: After this piece, simply open `./tempfile` with `Dataset('./tempfile', mode='r')` as the questions shows