# netCDF4 - Python error

Tags: python, anaconda, netcdf

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong? I am using python-conda, and the files I have from http://meop40.troja.mff.cuni.cz:11180/gw.projekt/data.stratopauza/netcdf.profily/
Why it tells me that file doesn't exist?

```css
>>> import netCDF4
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> url = 'http://meop40.troja.mff.cuni.cz:11180/gw.projekt/data.stratopauza/netcdf.profily/atmPrf_C001.2010.227.00.03.G04_2013.3520_nc'
>>> nc = netCDF4.Dataset(url)
**syntax error, unexpected WORD_WORD, expecting SCAN_ATTR or SCAN_DATASET or SCAN_ERROR
context: <!DOCTYPE^ HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"><html><head><title>404 Not Found</title></head><body><h1>Not Found</h1><p>The requested URL /gw.projekt/data.stratopauza/netcdf.profily/atmPrf_C001.2010.227.00.03.G04_2013.3520_nc.dds was not found on this server.</p><hr><address>Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu) Server at meop40.troja.mff.cuni.cz Port 11180</address></body></html>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "netCDF4\_netCDF4.pyx", line 1811, in netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset.__init__ (netCDF4\_netCDF4.c:12626)
IOError: NetCDF: file not found**
```

Answer (score 2):

`NetCDF4.Dataset()` can only access remote NetCDF files which are served by an OPeNDAP service, which can return metadata about the file. The error message returned is incorrect and misleading.

There is a brief tutorial, which mentions this and gives basic information at: http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/#section1

I downloaded the file and had no problem opening the file. You should use the method in the answer to your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/a/44622713/1211981

**Update:**
Go to:

http://meop40.troja.mff.cuni.cz:11180/gw.projekt/data.stratopauza/netcdf.profily/

Click one or more of the links and save to a folder where you will run your script. Change your script or python commands to:

```
>>> url = 'atmPrf_C001.2010.227.00.03.G04_2013.3520_nc'
>>> nc = netCDF4.Dataset(url)
```

`netCDF4.Dataset()` will take either a url or a local file name and work the same way. In this case it will recognize the file as a NetCDF / OPeNDAP compatible.

Comment: And after you downloaded it, where did you place it? I am not sure if I am doing it right, or can you show that code please. I am very desparate.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "netCDF4\_netCDF4.pyx", line 1811, in netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset.__init__ (netCDF4\_netCDF4.c:12626)
IOError: No such file or directory I got this everytime. I tried to read it from URL and it sorta worked. Everytime I use Dataset, error occurs somehow. But thank you for your edit.